# Looking for a lightweight Python web framework with minimal configuration

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, web-frameworks

I realise that web application frameworks are well documented, yet having tried 2 Python frameworks and found that are neither are suitable for my task, I hope you'll understand the need for this question.

I'm looking for a lightweight, "micro" framework for Python with the following features:

- Basic HTML layout management
- Features for HTML forms, tables etc.
- Authentication and session management
- Preferably integrable with mod_wsgi
- Seamless importing of packages

That's it. You may ask why I need a framework for this at all - I don't. But it would save a lot of time, and I'm very surprised that I can't find something like this.

I'm reasonably advanced in Python but want to deal with the HTML and authentication as effortlessly as possible. I have a lot of existing code that I would like to be called from within the framework. I don't require an ORM or DAL, I would like my existing classes to continue to use their own MySQLdb driver. Inevitably, for authentication to be handled, an ORM or DAL will be included, but I just won't use it for anything other than authentication.

I have tried web2py and Grok, both supposedly lightweight, configuration-free frameworks, yet both were far too high-level.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As soon as you add "features for HTML forms, tables etc." you lose the "micro" bit. And what does "seamless importing of packages" even *mean*?

Comment: Out of the frameworks I have used, the higher level they are, the more caveats they tend to have for importing packages/modules. I simply meant with as few caveats as possible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should have a look at [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).

- It comes with [jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/) as a template language.
- It doesn't contain any ORM.
- There are [lots of well supported extensions](http://flask.pocoo.org/extensions/) for sessions, forms, ORM, etc.

Comment: And, in addition, it's *much* lower level than web2py (cannot speak for Grok). +1

Answer (score 4):

You can also try [WebPy](http://webpy.org/).

Answer (score 3):

The full (?) list of python web frameworks [is given here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks).  [This slideshow](http://www.slideshare.net/r1chardj0n3s/web-microframework-battle) compares 10 micro frameworks and should be of intrest.  Not all of them will tick your boxes but at least it should give some hints as to their pros/cons.

Answer (score 0):

I propose looking into [web.py](http://webpy.org/) and [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org).

Web.py is incredibly simple to use with a power of a full web framework.
I used it for OData implementation with great success.